# separate two lists by difference in elements in them

Tags: list, scala, collections, scala-collections, scalaz

If I have

```
val incomingIds : List[Int] = ....
val existingIds : List[Int] = //this makes db calls and find existing records (only interested in returning ids)
```

Now next I want to compare `incomingIds` with `existingIds` in a following way

say I have

```
val incomingIds : List[Int] = List(2,3,4,5)
val existingIds : List[Int] = List(1,2,3,6)
```

What above sample suggests is that my API should be able to find `ids` that are subject for deletion (ones that exist in `incomingIds` but not in `existingIds`). In this sample `existingIds` have `1,4,5` but they aren't there in `incomingIds` means `1,4,5` should go into

```
val idsForDeletion :List[Int]
```

and there will be another list call it

```
val idsForInsertion :List[Int].
```

so `6` should go into `idsForInsertion` list.

Is there a simple way to partition lists such a way?

Comment: I think what you're technically looking for here is symmetric difference of sets. It would be way easier to use `Set[A]` here: `(s1 diff s2, s2 diff s1)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can filter the items from each list that aren't included in the other one using scala's [`filterNot`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@filterNot(p:A=%3EBoolean):Repr) function:

```
val idsForDeletion = existingIds.filterNot(incomingIds.toSet)
val idsForInsertion = incomingIds.filterNot(existingIds.toSet)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `diff`

```
def diff(that: collection.Seq[A]): List[A]
```

It Computes the multiset difference between this list and another sequence.

```
scala> val incomingIds : List[Int] = List(2,3,4,5)
incomingIds: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val existingIds : List[Int] = List(1,2,3,6)
existingIds: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 6)

scala> (incomingIds diff existingIds).toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(4, 5)

scala> (existingIds diff incomingIds).toSet
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 6)
```